# sample code of ejs.render inside script tag not working it gives error as variable is not defined

Tags: ejs

`<script src="ejs.js"></script>`
`<script>`
`let people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];`
`let html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});`
`</script>`

This code is in official docs of ejs, but when used in ejs file I get error

people is not defined

How do I resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm that you're using [browser version](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ejs@3.1.6/ejs.min.js) of Ejs? I copied the same code and it is working for me.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wc4ojan/1/) and it console out the result without error.

```js
let people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];
let html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
console.log(html);
```